# What is the differece between root terminal and sudo?

Tags: terminal, sudo, root, non-root-user

Environment:debian8+lxde.
There are two terminal in system tools:LXTerminal and Root Terminal.

[image]

When to login with a normal user (not root user),and System tools--Root Terminal,you can have administrator privileges.

What is the differece between executing command in root terminal and executing it with sudo in LXTerminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man page `sudo`:

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or
>   another user, as specified by the security policy.  The invoking
>        user's real (not effective) user ID is used to determine the user name with which to query the security policy.

So in such case `sudo` is a tool, but `root` is a user.

and when you use root terminal that mean you are logging in with user root.

and when you run a command using `sudo`, you actually asking root (by default) to run it for you, and there is a log that log every calling for `sudo` in `/var/log/auth.log`, so at the end both of them run the command by user root.

Answer (score 0):

The Root Terminal : A terminal for the root user , it can be opened by clicking on the **Root Terminal**  or from the `lxterminal` through `gksu lxterminal` (LXDE) or `gksu konsole` (KDE) after asking for the `root` password.

The LXTerminal is used by both Root and users , users will be asked for the `sudo` password

Answer (score 0):

The difference can be seen like this: when you use root priviledges, you can do "anything", including installing malwares, deleting important or critical files, etc.

login as a regular user is good, because your rights (and hence the damages) are limited. You can lose all your documents, but not mess up (too much) your system.

Think about sudo as holding the crown (aka, the root priviledges) for a limited time. You are king while you hold the crown (ie, you are root while the sudo lasts), but before and after that you are a regular user, with limited rights so with limited capabilities to damage things other than your own files.

From a security point of view this is preferable to having a root terminal opened, where you would need to be really careful about every commands you type, at all time.

Sudo allows you to run commands when needed, and be back to your regular user faster.

The root terminal however can be usefull if you are about to run many commands as root. But for regular users usage, this almost never happem.

(logging as root is even worse: then every thung you run (browser, etc) run as root and a malicious user (or a mistake) in any of those programs could install a rootkit, or delete more than it should)